# How do you get rid of the right and left sides of a border without getting rid of the top and bottom sides?

Tags: html, css

"How do you get rid of the right and left sides of a border without getting rid of the top and bottom sides?"
^Title says it all.

Comment: you can try border-left ,border-right like,is that your problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
border: none;
border-bottom, border-top: 1px solid black;
```

or whatever thickness and color you want.

or the other way round:

```
border-left, border-right: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following format where you specify all property values:

```
.dom {
    border-width:10px 0px 10px 0px;
}
```